# Find $3$ non-isomorphic countable models

Tags: model-theory

I need to find a complete theory with exactly $3$ non-isomorphic countable models. It is from exercise $2.3.15$ in "Model Theory" (Chang-Keisler 2012).

[image]

I think case $1$ in exercise $2.3.15$ is countably saturated because it is $DLO$ without end points. Case $2$ is countably atomic because it is countable, and case $3$ is not countable. But I am not sure about these conclusions and need confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first model is *not* saturated because it does not realize the type $\{x>c_n:n\in\omega\}$.

It is instead atomic. Every type is isolated by one of the formulas $x<c_0$ and $c_n<x<c_{n+1}$ for $n\in\omega$.

The second model is not atomic because it realizes the type $\{x>c_n:n\in\omega\}$ which is not isolated.

Neither it is saturated as it omits the type $\{l>x>c_n:n\in\omega\}$, where $l$ is the limit above.

The third model is saturated.
In fact, non-algebraic types either contain $c_n<x<c_{n+1}$ for $n\in\omega$ or they contain  $\{x>c_n:n\in\omega\}$.
These formulas and type define a DLO.
But DLO are $\omega$-saturated.

Comment: Answer to your first comment. Note that $l$ realizes $\{x>c_n:n\in\omega\}$ but doent realize $\{l>x>c_n:n\in\omega\}$.

Comment: Answer to your second comment. You first have to understand well the case $n=3$. Only when you feel confident about that; ask about the case $n>3$ in a new post (but at that point it you may find it straightforward).